# How can i implement a progressive darkening effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i implement a progressive darkening effect where each interaction adds 10% more black or color to the square?

I tried to work with `filter: brightness`, the value of darkness is 0%, but the value of lightness is less 1000% and not every color at 1000% gives a white background.

```
const shadingMode = (elem) => {
  let currentBrightness = elem.style.filter.slice(11, -2);
  if (currentBrightness > 0) {
    console.log("currentBrightness " + currentBrightness);
    elem.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness - 10}%)`;
    console.log("elem.style.filter 2: " + elem.style.filter);
  } else {
    currentBrightness = 0;
  }
};
const lightenMode = (elem) => {
  let currentBrightness = elem.style.filter.slice(11, -2);
  if (currentBrightness < 1000) {
    console.log("currentBrightness " + currentBrightness);
    elem.style.filter = `brightness(${parseInt(currentBrightness) + 100}%)`;
    console.log("elem.style.filter 2: " + elem.style.filter);
  } else {
    currentBrightness = 800;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

When the left mouse button is clicked, the square will become darker.
When you click with the right button, the square will become brighter

I hope my example is useful to you.

**Example 1**

```js
const square = document.getElementById('square');

const darkenSquare = () => {
    let currentBrightness = square.dataset.brightness || 100;
    currentBrightness = parseInt(currentBrightness) - 10;

    if (currentBrightness >= 0) {
        square.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness}%)`;
        square.dataset.brightness = currentBrightness;
    }
};

const lightenSquare = () => {
    let currentBrightness = square.dataset.brightness || 100;
    currentBrightness = parseInt(currentBrightness) + 10;

    if (currentBrightness <= 100) {
        square.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness}%)`;
        square.dataset.brightness = currentBrightness;
    }
};

square.addEventListener('click', darkenSquare);
square.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    lightenSquare();
});
```

```css
.square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="square"></div>
```

**Example 2**

In this example I have used HSL color value. This allows by changing the light value to change the color to black or white.

Left mouse button will fade to black. Right will light up to white

```js
const square = document.getElementById('square');

const darkenSquare = () => {
    let currentBrightness = square.dataset.brightness;
    currentBrightness = parseInt(currentBrightness) - 10;

    if (currentBrightness >= 0) {
        square.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(240, 100%,${currentBrightness}%)`
        square.dataset.brightness = currentBrightness;
    }
};

const lightenSquare = () => {
    let currentBrightness = square.dataset.brightness;
    currentBrightness = parseInt(currentBrightness) + 10;

    if (currentBrightness <= 100) {
        square.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(240, 100%,${currentBrightness}%)`
        square.dataset.brightness = currentBrightness;
    }
};

square.addEventListener('click', darkenSquare);
square.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    lightenSquare();
});
```

```css
.square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="square" style="background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);" data-brightness="50"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have problems with the lightening mode. I can't find a single filter: brightness value for all colors. Because of this, some colors are completely white already at a value of 800, and some at 1200 are not completely bleached. In your solution, you have to click a few dozen times with the right mouse button on the square, but the result is not noticed by eye. I'm trying to find another option besides filter: brightness

Comment: @StepaFrolov, In my post I added Example 2. Please look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would solve the problem like so: I'd place the element of which I want to change the darkness inside of a wrapper, alongside a "filter" element. The filter element is just a square the same size, with background color black. In js we read the opacity of the filter element, and increase it. I find that this is the "cleanest" version, as it requires barely any js code.

[Link to my Codepen](https://codepen.io/Xaverrrrr/pen/rNQoOjV)

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="filter"></div>
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#element{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#filter{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

JS:

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper")
let filter = document.querySelector("#filter");

wrapper.addEventListener("click", function(){
  let currentOpacity = Number(filter.style.opacity);
  if(currentOpacity < 1) filter.style.opacity = currentOpacity + 0.1;
})
```

Comment: In the `#filter`, you might want to add `pointer-events: none;` to avoid interactions and ensure the original content can be accessed without problems. Also, for the JS you might want to check if the opacity value is larger than 1 after adding 0.1 (currently it has no upper limit, although the browser will limit the value)

Comment: Also, consider to add `transition` property to make the opacity changing smoothly. Sizing of both child elements can follow the wrapper size by setting width and height to 100%.

Comment: @Raptor Thank you for pointing that out. I missed, that the element could potentially have interactive elements, so setting `pointer-events` to `none` makes a lot of sense. As you already mentioned, I didn't limit the `opacity` to `1`, since the browser already limits it. However, I did implement that change too, for "convention" reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your shadingMode function seems to implement a darkening effect using the brightness CSS filter. It takes an element elem as input and reduces its brightness by 10% on each interaction.

However, there are a couple of issues in the code that need to be addressed:

The currentBrightness variable will be a string with a percentage symbol, e.g., "90%". When you use .slice(11, -2), it removes the % symbol and takes the numeric part as a string. You should convert it to a number using parseInt() or parseFloat() before performing arithmetic operations.

Since you are using the brightness() filter, which modifies the brightness relative to the original brightness, you should set an initial brightness value for the element to work correctly.

Here's the corrected version :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Progressive Darkening and Lightening Effect</title>
  <style>
    #square {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: #8b1d1d;
      transition: filter 0.3s ease;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="square" onclick="toggleShade(this)"></div>
  <button onclick="toggleLighten(this)">Lighten</button>

  <script>
    const shadingMode = (elem) => {
      let currentBrightness = parseFloat(elem.style.filter.slice(11, -1));
      if (isNaN(currentBrightness)) {
        currentBrightness = 100;
      }

      if (currentBrightness > 0) {
        elem.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness - 10}%)`;
      } else {
        currentBrightness = 0;
      }
    };

    const lightenMode = (elem) => {
      let currentBrightness = parseFloat(elem.style.filter.slice(11, -1));
      if (isNaN(currentBrightness)) {
        currentBrightness = 100;
      }

      if (currentBrightness < 1000) {
        elem.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness + 100}%)`;
      } else {
        currentBrightness = 800; // Set a fallback value, if needed
      }
    };

    const toggleShade = (elem) => {
      shadingMode(elem);
    };

    const toggleLighten = (elem) => {
      lightenMode(elem.previousElementSibling); // Find the square element and pass it to lightenMode
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this corrected version, I used parseFloat() to convert currentBrightness to a number. Additionally, if the brightness is not set (NaN), the function sets an initial brightness of 100% (fully bright). Then, it reduces the brightness by 10% on each interaction by updating the elem.style.filter property.

Make sure to add an event listener to call this function when interacting with the element, such as on a click event. Also, ensure that the element you pass to shadingMode has a filter property, which can be modified to control its brightness.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I have problems with the lightening mode. I can't find a single filter: brightness value for all colors. Because of this, some colors are completely white already at a value of 800, and some at 1200 are not completely bleached. May be i do something wrong

Comment: It would be really helpfl iuf you could make a runnable snippet to demonstrate what has been 'cured' - otherwise it looks too much liks a fluent but slightly incomplete ChatGTP answer (apologies if it was all your own work - it could just do with a little bit more detail to build confidence).

Comment: Hope this will help you:     `const lightenMode = (elem) => {
      let currentBrightness = parseFloat(elem.style.filter.slice(11, -1));
      if (isNaN(currentBrightness)) {
        currentBrightness = 100;
      }

      if (currentBrightness < 1000) {
        elem.style.filter = `brightness(${currentBrightness + 100}%)`;
      } else {
        currentBrightness = 800; // Set a fallback value, if needed
      }
    };`